# Android and IntelliJ 14: Cannot resolve classes of google play services added as dependency

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, google-play-services, android-sdk-2.3

I'm migrating an Android Application from eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA 14, created without gradle.
The project works perfectly with eclipse, but for whatever reason I can't use the google play services with intelliJ.

I looked online and found many way to import the play services but none of them worked for me so far, I have errors of the type  `Cannot resolve LocationClient` every time I have an import to a play services class (eg: `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;`)

I have the google play services lib project in my workspace. it is added as a module to the application project and I checked that the play services library is added as a dependency under `project settings` > `module` > `dependency`.

I also tried to directly add the jar as a dependency but it's not more successfull.

I also found a lot of people suggesting using gradle but I don't want to switch to gradle because I don't want to change de build process for everybody working on this project.

What am I missing in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: double check your `imports section` to be sure that you are importing `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;` and not `android.location.LocationClient`

Comment: yes I checked,the line in my post is a copy/past from the import in my project.
And in eclipse this project works perfectly

Comment: try `rebuilding` project. Check again if you imported `jars` correctly...

Comment: I did, i imported it multiple times (as a former Eclipse project, with the gradle wrapper, ...), invalidated the caches, ... but nothing worked.

Comment: I'd suggest using Android Studio. Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: acytually I found the problem: google deprecated the LocationClient from the play services library at the same time a I switched IDEs and when I imported the new play services project in my project the class was now missing, which made me believe that the entire google play services library was not found...
Thanks for your help!